# show hide multiple rows using button click jquery

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, jquery

I have a html table like so

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<div>
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr></tr> --visible row 1
    <tr></tr> --show\hide on click by visible row1
    <tr></tr> --show\hide on click by visible row1
    </table>
    </div>
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr></tr> --visible row 2
    <tr></tr> --show\hide on click by visible row2
    <tr></tr> --show\hide on click by visible row2
    <tr></tr> --show\hide on click by visible row2
    </table>
    </div>
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr></tr> --visible row 3
    <tr></tr> --show\hide on click by visible row3
    </table>
    </div>
<div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How do i perform show\hide of the tr's by clicking the corresponding visible rows. I have seen examples where one row next one is removed, but how do i show hide tr within the parent table of the visible row and hide all child row not in 1 st positon.

If someone could post the jquery function, i can work out of that. thanks much appreciated.

Comment: assign a class to the TRs and the click TRs then do nextSibling(clickclass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure about page load state, following will hide all but first row of each table on load and apply click handler to top row

```
$('table').each(function(){
    $('tr:first', this) .click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().toggle()
    })
  $('tr:gt(0)', this).hide()
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Rd8PU/

Comment: Thanks a lot charlietfl you made my day. I worked on top of your jsfiddle\idea and created what i needed. you are the best.  my final fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lazyboy4ever/T7Vtn/1/      also is there a way to toggle the <a> tag with different content on each click.

Comment: also is there a way to toggle the <a> tag with different content on each click. as you can see in the final jsfiddle

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/T7Vtn/3/  You should add some classes to tables or wrapper divs to reference only these tables in case you have others in page, or other pages that script may end up on. Dangerous using tags only as a selector

Comment: if you hit show hide twice and then try to click the individual rows, the clicked row does not expand. Is it because of the hiderows method in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a class to the visible rows (class="clickable")

then here is your function

```
$('tr.clickable').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks chris for your help, yours works as well but charlie's suited my requirement. thanks a lot, you are great.

Comment: was very late when I did the change..this version should be better. The whole thing would need extending for various scenarios beyond the simple cases covered  http://jsfiddle.net/T7Vtn/8/